# Securing an FTP Server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I am tasked to setup a FTP Server, which will receive file uploads from different locations and users. They asked me to setup a anonymous FTP, but that doesn't seem to be secure.

I am using Windows 2008R2 and I have configured (previously) a Windows 2003 R2 based Blind drop ftp for one of our local LANS previously, in which users would simply connect via filezilla or commandline and upload without the need for entering a username / passwd.

I have successfully configured Blind Drop on Windows 2008R2 as well, we have a requirement that LAN users can upload anonymously but anyone coming from the internet would need a username and password and they would LAND in there own Directory.

In 2008R2, I have denied listing for ftp root, how would I configure this that it will only deny listing to anonymous users as the users which connect via a username and password will go in there own respective directories.

If this is easier to setup on Linux (Ubuntu), I will go for that, I am still reading FTP user isolation but a step by step would help.

Also, is there a way to disable anonymous login on external connections but allow on LAN connection ?

Help would be appreciated !
Kind Regards

Update : Also, what sort of hardware you would recommend for this type of FTP Server ? I have spec'd up a Machine with the new Corei Series of processor and 4GB RAM with 2 x 1TB Hard Drives 64MB Cache. We will also be cleaning up the FTP Once every Week so the data won't go beyond the size of the drives or we can add two more drives to it if need be, Do you think this should be OK for a FTP server considering that it will get busier, from 1 - 10 connections (uploading) per hour to 10 - 50 Connections per hour for uploading only. We have a dedicated internet pipe for this FTP only. - Thanks so much for all the prompt responses !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set up FTP user isolation. This should help:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/305/configuring-ftp-75-user-isolation/

Comment: I am going to try this too on a test box I have and see if I have any problems, one thing is, that do I need to have active directory for this or I can create local users on the server itself and then assign permissions on there respective ftp folders and enable user isolation in IIS Manager for that respective FTP Site ?

Comment: You can use local accounts or domain accounts.

Answer (score 2):

My preference would be to setup an SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP) server with chrooted user directories and public key authentication.  This is fairly straightforward to do; I can provide the commands and configuration required to do this if you want to go this route.

Comment: Thanks gravyface, I haven't setup a SFTP server yet on Linux, after discussions I have proposed that we should create users for each of our locations and they should LAND in there own respective Directory, I will then need some users who would be able to upload but won't be able to list or change directories - which FTP server you would recommend ? What does chrooted mean ? :-) Sorry I am new to linux world. If you can provide a step by step doc for Ubuntu 11.04 I will setup and test it out.

Comment: I have updated my question too with a small question :-) your advise / suggestion will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Your hardware should be fine; the Internet connection will be the bottleneck.

Comment: If you have no Linux experience, perhaps this is not the solution for you.  It's not complicated per se, but there's ongoing maintenance to think about (adding users/getting public keys from them/moving data to/from the FTP server).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Debian (and I guess ubuntu too), ignoring best practices using ssh and sftp, you can set ftp with chrooted virtual user(s) using **pureftpd**, which is the best ftp server I experienced till now.

Comment: Thanks for the input, can you please provide a how-to for Ubuntu linux, I am going to google right after this but if you have a straight forward write up - that would certainly help !

Answer (score 0):

I installed pureftpd on a NAS with a Nux busyBox but not on a Debian's like machine.

Pls find anyway the best doc I found (sorry, some are in french) :
http://forum.qnapclub.fr/topic/1259-creation-repertoire-ftp/
http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=2851
http://drpixel.tuxfamily.org/index.php?2006/06/25/8-pure-ftpd-installation-et-configuration-1-2
http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README

I also wrote an installation shell [here](http://forum.qnapclub.fr/topic/1259-creation-repertoire-ftp/page__view__findpost__p__11650), that might help also on other Nux OS.

I also wrote a hook shell sothat the received files are unitary controlled before saving them locally. It's not a shared script but I can share or send it if sbdy needs it.